# Primesfaces : how to get the value of a Filter column text

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

given the following primefaces Data

```
<p:dataTable value="#{cc.attributes.playerCollection}" var="player"
    widgetVar="playerWidgetTable" emptyMessage="#{uimsg.ui_not_recordsfound}">
    <!-- filter event handler  -->
    <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{cc.attributes.viewBean.listenFilter}" update="@this"/>

    <!-- Player first name  -->
    <p:column id="firstnameColumn" headerText="#{uimsg.firstname}"
        filterBy="#{player.firstName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{player.firstName}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

how does someone get (on the server side) the filter "Text" value, given by the user in the filter textcolumn ?

i tried to listen to the filter event with "listenFilter":

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PlayerListBean implements Serializable {

......

    public void listenFilter(FilterEvent event) {
        // update datasource
        Map<String, String> tempString = event.getFilters();

        System.out.println("size filter: "+ tempString.size());
        for (String key : tempString.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key: " + key + " \t values: "
                    + tempString.get(key));

        }

    }

}
```

but I can't start something with it.
are they any other options ? like working with the DataTable as a bound Component, or else ?

thanks

Comment: Can i ask why you want to get the value of the filter text?

Comment: oh simple: to evaluate it and start some Front/Back end operations, depending on its value...

Comment: I still don't get it, the text entered in a filter on a datatable column automatically filters the datatable. What would you need with it?

Comment: the point is ... I just need to know which value on the field was entered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I normally do is to use an actual DataModel to feed to the dataTable component instead of using a plain collection, like you seem to be doing (you didn't post the rest of your bean). I  extend the LazyDataModel class and override the load() method, whose signature is:

```
public List load(int first, int size, String column, SortOrder order, Map<String, String> filter);
```

In this case, the filter field (map) contains whatever the user entered on each filter. Also, you don't really need any ajax listeners for the filter. I use this in my projects and it works just fine. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: is there no other way that this ?

Comment: The dataTable component knows if it has a lazy data model or a collection. If it's a collection, it would make sense to imagine that they filter the data using pure javascript. That way, the contents of the filter event wouldn't make it all the way to the bean. But that's me assuming, I am no primefaces developer.

Answer (score 3):

This works just fine for me...

```
public void listenFilter(FilterEvent event) {

    DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();
    Map<String, String>  filters = table.getFilters();
    //grab the value from the required map key (somePropertyName if your filterBy 
     looks like filterBy="#{myBean.somePropertyName}") ... 

}
```

Comment: the scope doesn#t have a role to play here... what we need is the envelopping Bean. Viewscoped Bean is enough to deal with dataTable (and Ajax request ) because every action occurs on within a singe View (request as well as the respone).. so ViewScoped is actually valid ... SessionScoped will change nothing.